# HASHBYTES() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to use HASHBYTES() in TSQL code?

the problem with my code is

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET hash_value=HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(varchar(max),col1),convert(varchar(max),col2),..)
```

returns `NULL`.
Can you advise me, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why cast the columns to `varchar(max)`? The whole input is truncated to [8000 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) takes two arguments. The first is the hashing algorithm (`MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1`) and the second is the value to hash. If you have any other value as algorithm you will have `NULL` as a result.

You will also have `NULL` as result if the value in the second parameter is `NULL`.

Perhaps you can use something like this.

```
hashbytes('MD5', coalesce(convert(varchar(max),col1), '') + 
                 coalesce(convert(varchar(max),col2), '') +
                 ...)
```

Concatenate the strings with `+` and use `coalesce` to handle `NULL` values.

Comment: UPDATE mytable    SET hash_value=HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(varchar(max),col1),convert(varchar(max),col2),..)

Comment: @pawan - You can't have more than two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what col1 is in your code example this may not answer your question however the first argument to `HASHBYTES` should be the `algorithm`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) the syntax is:

```
 HashBytes ('<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )<algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1
```

**Edit** The MSDN article also explains that the input parameter is either a string or a reference to a variable of type varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary, it is a single input. You are passing in multiple input parameters. I am surprised however that you are getting null rather than the error I get when I try and run the function which is `The hashbytes function requires 2 argument(s).`. The most likely cause of you getting a NULL result is if your input value is null, i.e. your column you are converting to varchar is null. If you run `select hashbytes('md5', convert(varchar(max), null))` you will get a `NULL` result.

Comment: UPDATE mytable    SET hash_value=HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(varchar(max),col1),convert(varchar(max),col2),..)

Comment: UPDATE mytable    SET hash_value=HASHBYTES('MD5',convert(varchar(max),col1),convert(varchar(max),col2),..)